# jquery livequery not fixing autosuggest?

Tags: jquery

I have an autosuggest feature enabled in search products field of order items section here:

The issue here is, when I add new search product fields (green button under order items title), auto suggest plugin is not functioning in the new fields. From a few articles I read, I thought autosuggest would fix this issue, but not fixing. Any idea why?

auto suggest:

```
$("#PRODUCTNAME").autocomplete("orders.cs.asp?Process=ListProducts", {
    selectFirst: false
});

$("#PRODUCTNAME").result(function(event, data, formatted) {
    if (data)
        $("#PRICE").html(data[1]);
        $("#ID").html(data[2]);
        $("#UNITPRICE").html(data[1]);
        $("#PRODUCTID").html(data[2]);
});
```

adding new field

```
$('#AddProduct').livequery('click', function(event) {
    $('#OrderProducts').append('<div class="column width50"><input type="text" id="PRODUCTNAME" name="PRODUCTNAME" value=""  class="width98" /><input type="hidden" id="PRODUCTID" name="PRODUCTID" /><input type="hidden" id="UNITPRICE" name="UNITPRICE" /><small>Search Productsvalue="" class="width98" /><small>Quantity</small></div><div class="column width30"><span class="prices">Unit Price:<br />Total Price:</span></div>');
     return false;
```

> });

html

```
        <fieldset>
            <h2>Order Items</h2>
            <div id="OrderProducts">
                <a href="#" id="AddProduct"><img src="icons/add.png" alt="Add" /></a><a href="#" id="DeleteProduct"><img src="icons/cancel.png" alt="Cancel" /></a>
            </div>  

                <input type="hidden" id="PRODUCTID" name="PRODUCTID" />
                <input type="hidden" id="UNITPRICE" name="UNITPRICE" />
                <small>Search Products</small>
            </div>
            <div class="column width20">
                <input type="text" id="UNITPRICE" name="UNITPRICE" value="" class="width98" />
                <small>Quantity</small>
            </div>
            <div class="column width30">
                <span class="prices">Unit Price:<br />Total Price:</span>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
});
```

Comment: You have the trailing }); after the "adding new field" script, right?

Comment: I may have badly copy/pasted. sorry for that, I will try fixing it. But yes, I have the trailing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon the problem is that you don't add the autocompletion to the new element. You don't actually need livequery.  Therefore, changing your second block of code like so:

```
$('#AddProduct').click(function() {
        var adding = $('<div class="column width50"><input type="text" id="PRODUCTNAME" name="PRODUCTNAME" value=""  class="width98" /><input type="hidden" id="PRODUCTID" name="PRODUCTID" /><input type="hidden" id="UNITPRICE" name="UNITPRICE" /><small>Search Products</small></div><div class="column width20"><input type="text" id="UNITPRICE" name="UNITPRICE" value="" class="width98" /><small>Quantity</small></div><div class="column width30"><span class="prices">Unit Price:<br />Total Price:</span></div>');        
        $('#OrderProducts').append(adding);

        adding.find("#PRODUCTNAME").autocomplete("orders.cs.asp?Process=ListProducts", {
            selectFirst: false
        }).result(function(event, data, formatted) {
            if (data) {
                adding.find("#PRICE").val(data[1]);
                adding.find("#ID").val(data[2]);
                adding.find("#UNITPRICE").val(data[1]);
                adding.find("#PRODUCTID").val(data[2]);
            }
        });

        return false;
});
```

I reckon that should do it, barring one or two small tweaks here and there.

Just two comments on how you are handling your form elements by the way - your method results in more than one element possessing the same ID, which is invalid (although it will work) - perhaps alter it to select based on classes instead.  Secondly, you used the html function to set the value of the inputs - not even sure that works, so in my proposed solution I replaced the html calls with val.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am just little confused with IDs. Its been always working, why do you say I should change them to classes?

Comment: It will work (as in the DOM will still behave ok), however, having more than one element with the same ID will cause XHTML validation to fail.  The point of an ID is to identify an individual element, rather than a group.  Since you are adding many elements that have the same use or 'class', it does make more sense to get elements by their class. Something else I just realised by the way is that you will end up with duplicate input names with your current method (so only the last set of inputs will be visible server side).

Comment: Than I will go with class. Oh and reason I used .html, not .val is because I want to them both in input field and in span (unit price for example). 
That, I plan to handle by adding +(i++)+ to name fields.